# nginx = / location pattern not working

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to serve a static html page on the root domain, and proxy everything else to uwsgi. As a quick test I tried to divert to two different static pages:

```
server {
    server_name *.example.dev;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    listen      80;
    charset     utf-8;

    location = / {
        root   /www/src/;
    }

    location / {
        root /www/test/;
    }
}
```

This seems to be what http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location says you can do. But I'm always getting sent to the test site, even on the `/` request by visiting `http://www.example.dev` in my browser.

Curl output:

```
$ curl http://www.example.dev -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.example.dev/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.50.51...
* Connected to www.example.dev (192.168.50.51) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: www.example.dev
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.8.0
< Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 01:11:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 415
< Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 02:53:27 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "552dd2a7-19f"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

And the output from the nginx access log:

```
192.168.50.1 - - [19/May/2015:01:17:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 415 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

So I  decided to comment out the test location. So I have only the `location = / { ...` block. Nginx now 404s and logs the following error:

`2015/05/19 01:24:12 [error] 3116#0: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.50.1, server: *.example.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.dev"`

Which is the default root in the original nginx conf file? I guess this confirms my `location = /` pattern is **not** matching.

I added `$uri` to the access log and see that it is showing `/index.html` which I guess means the first location pattern **is** matching, but then it goes into the second location block? So now I just need to figure out how to serve my index.html from the `/` block, or just add another block like: `location =/index.html`

Comment: How are you testing the {/} request? Could you share the URL? The documentation says that it must be an *exact* match. Did you make the request in the browser or using curl?

Comment: @teambob I simply went to `http://www.example.dev` in the browser. I am assuming that is the `/` request, but maybe that's where I am going wrong. The URL isn't hosted anywhere online yet – just in a VM.

Comment: Have you tried [http://www.example.dev/](http://www.example.dev/) Look at the Live HTTP Headers extension for Firefox and Chrome - that will show you exactly what is going to the server

Comment: @teambob I've added the output from `curl -v` if that helps. Is the same with and without the trailing slash. Also, the output from the access log.

Comment: Read docs http://nginx.org/r/index. It has exactly your case with explanation

Answer (score 0):

according to @Alexey Ten commented, in [ngx_http_index doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index):

> It should be noted that using an index file causes an internal redirect, and the request can be processed in a different location. For example, with the following configuration:

```
location = / {
    index index.html;
}

location / {
    ...
}
```

> a “/” request will actually be processed in the second location as “/index.html”.

In your case, request to "/" will not get /www/src/index.html, but /www/test/index.html.